# Manipulating forms input in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am very new to Ruby and ROR. Been learning by myself for self interest. I am toying with constructing an app but i have reached a stage whereby i need help.

Here's the scenario:

I have a form that requires users to input their employer which is tagged to the :employer object.

Somewhere in the app, the users are listed down in a `ul` if their `employer` input matches the company name in a jobsearch of an api as such:

`@user.employer == @job.company`

However, there is an error of `undefined method employer for #<Class:0x007f9d54f66e10>`. Checked on the console and tried `User.first.employer`. This returns the employer which was keyed in in the form when signing up.

I have tried defining `employer` in the controller and view files but to no avail.

Comment: Are you sure that `@user` is an instance of `User` class?

Comment: I have added `@user = User.find(params[:id])`, and it returns `Couldn't find User with 'id'=` probably since I was not logged in and it could not find an 'id'. How should I instantiate the user variable such that it is appropriate in this case?

Comment: You need to make sure that `id` you are passing, a record does exist with that `id`. Otherwise, it will throw an error.

Comment: Yes I have done that.  I have added `id` as an integer into the `Users` table in the `User` model.  Thanks for taking your time to read this, Arslan.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: To make things clearer, I have added a block such that all users in the system are goes through this matching as such:                                     `<% @users.each do |user| %>
            <li>
                <% unless @user.employer == @job.company %>`